# Numpy: resizing a grayscale image with the last dimension as np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an grayscale 2 images of (3000, 3000), which I resized it into (128, 128, 1) each using `np.resize` and stacked them using `np.stack`, to produce a 4D np array of (2, 128, 128, 1).

However, I realized the last dimension is in the form of integer. How do I resize an image to a specific dimension and keep the last dimension (the number of channel, which is 1 for grayscale) in an np array form and not in integer form?

```
from scipy.misc import imread
import numpy as np

image = imread('myimage.jpg')
image = np.resize(image, (128, 128, 1))

image2 = imread('myimage2.jpg')
image2 = np.resize(image2, (128, 128, 1))

images = np.stack((image, image2), axis = 0) #Shape of (2, 128, 128, 1).

#Problem: Is there a function that resizes in this fashion but detects the image as a grayscale one, which allows for the last dimension to be in np array?
```

When I do `print type(images[0, 0, 0, 0])`, I get an np.uint8. However, is it possible to convert it into an np array? Because currently, if the numbers remain as an integer, I get a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error.

What I am looking for is whether there's a function that resizes the (3000,3000) image that looks like:

```
[0.0, 0.0 .........]
[0.0, 0.0 .........]
...

#into something like:
[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0]....]
[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0]....]
...
```

After which I can stack the images together to create a 4D np array of
(N, H, W, C) shape. (N for number of images, H and W for height and width, C for number of channels of pixel values).

The code that let to the error is:

```
network = input_data(shape = [None, 256, 256, 1], name = 'input')
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation = 'relu', regularizer = 'L2')
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = fully_connected(network, 128, activation = 'tanh')
network = dropout(network, 0.8)
network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation = 'softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer = 'adam', learning_rate = '0.001', name = 'target')


model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose = None )
model.fit({'input': image_train}, {'target': 0}, n_epoch = 20, batch_size = 1,
          validation_set = ({'input': image_test}, {'target': 0}),
          snapshot_step = 100, show_metric = True, run_id = 'convnet_images')
```

Which gave me the error:

```
Run id: convnet_images
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
Exception in thread Thread-14:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 186, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 221, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the last dimension is in the form of integer"? It is not clear what you expect the output to look like. The complete `images` is a numpy array, therefore it also a numpy array in any projection.

Comment: For instance, something like [[249]] and not [249] for the last dimension - unless does np.resize already does this? Because my program seem to have an error accessing the last dimension it reads as an integer and not an array or list.

Comment: What do you get for `image[0,0,0]` and what would you like instead?

Comment: What is the command that should produce `[[249]]`? The question is really unclear, so I suggest you start from the beginning and think about what you need. Then, edit the question such that it includes explicitely, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added some more details in the question. Basically I found out the pixel values should not be an integer, but rather an np array which I can easily access the dimensions. This will make sense for coloured images as the last dimension must have at least a list of [R, G, B] values. In my case, because the image is grayscale, somehow my pixel values became an int instead of an array.

Comment: You need to decide if (a) you want to solve the problem of getting an error or (b) get the data in some user defined shape. In case (a) you need to show us the code that produces the error. In case (b) define **clearly** the output format (N,H, W,C are just letters, what is their meaning?)

Comment: Since `C = 1` in your case, I really do not see the problem. The output shape of (2, 128, 128, 1) exactly matches the criterion of  *(N for number of images, H and W for height and width, C for number of channels of pixel values)*

Comment: I think I finally understand what you want. Try `images = np.stack((image, image2), axis = 0)[:,:,:,:,np.newaxis]`. Although I doubt that will produce the desired result, it stil might get you around the error.

Comment: can you give a simple example with 2 specific ndarrays and the desired output?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest using `[:, :, :, :, np.newaxis] gives me a shape of (2, 128, 128, 1, 1) instead.
@Markus Dutschke The desired output is something I've written in the post (see the matrix).

Comment: @kwotsin Exactly! `(2, 128, 128, 1, 1)` is what you are asking for since `print type(images[0, 0, 0, 0; : ])` will give you a `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` instead of a scalar.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

I think he/she wants 4 dimensions, and what you have written gives him 5?